# Change Model Value of 2nd DropDown in wicket

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I have 2 dropdown in wicket and select any value from 1st dropdown then its changed 2nd dropdown list accordingly. Now If i am selecting any value from 2nd dropdown then data should changed, Its fine.

Now again If I selected default value/"All" value from 1st Dropdown then 2nd default value of 2nd dropdown should be "All" but instead of this its showing me selected value in dropdown.

Below is my code:

```
/*
countryList having -- All, India, Srilanka, US, UK
for All --> All, U.P., Delhi, colombo, England, New York, Washington
stateList for India --> All, U.P., Delhi
For Srilanka--> All,colombo, For US --> All, New York, Washington, For UK --> All, England
*/

DropDownChoice<Country> country = new DropDownChoice<Country>("country",
        new PropertyModel<Country>(params, "selectedCountry"),
        countryList, new ChoiceRenderer<Country>("countryName", "countryId"));
DropDownChoice<State> state = new DropDownChoice<State>("state",
        new PropertyModel<State>(params, "selectedState"),
        stateList, new ChoiceRenderer<State>("stateName", "stateId"));

country.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingIndicatingBehavior("onchange") {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (/* provide some condition*/) {
            params.setSelectedState("ALL");
        }
        target.add(state);
    }
});
```

But its not showing ALL for selectedstate in 2nd dropdown.

Comment: See my updated question.

Comment: `if (params.getSelectedCountry() == "ALL")` you should use `equals()` instead of `==` here. That could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: I have used also same but didnt worked...

Comment: I just wanted make sure . So when you are selecting india you want to show  `All , UP ,delhi`?

Comment: You can update the list according to the country selected and update the state dropdown

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed in the usage of `==` where you check the selected country. It is not very clear what is the type of `params` but from `new PropertyModel<Country>(params, "selectedCountry")` it looks like it is an object that has a property `selectedCountry` of type `Country`, where `Country` has `countryName` and `countryId`. So `if (params.getSelectedCountry() == "ALL")` is either not compiling or doing something wrong.

Comment: issue is not with if condition, My issue was after setting the 2nd dropdown value its not setting the 2nd dropdown value how could i set 2nd dropdown value after change the 1st dropdown value.

Comment: martin `params` is an object of `SearchParam` class type which is having a property `selectedCountry` of type `Country`. Now tell what you think about it.

Comment: In that case ` params.setSelectedState("ALL");` won't compile because `"All"` is not of type `Country`!